# How can I refactor this bunch of if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Imagine that I have a variable called **incomingValue** and I'm getting a number from an API as it's value. The values are between 0 to 1 and I'm setting two other variables depending on this value using bunch of if statements like you see below.

```
var incomingValue; // Set by an API
var setValueName;
var setValueIcon;
if (incomingValue < 0.10 ) { 
  setValueName = 'something'; 
  setValueIcon = 'something.png' 
}
if (incomingValue > 0.09 && incomingValue < 0.20 ) { 
  setValueName = 'somethingElse'; 
  setValueIcon = 'somethingElse.png';
}
```

In the actual implementation, I have around 10 if statements checking for specific intervals up until **1**. *e.g. do this if it's more than 0.10 but less than 0.16 and so on.*

As a JavaScript beginner it feels like this is not the right way to do things even though it gets the job done. How would I refactor this code?

*Update: As requested, I'm adding the full set of intervals that are used in the original code. I haven't included the full list before because the intervals don't follow a certain pattern.*

- 0 to 0.09
- 0.09 to 0.20
- 0.20 to 0.38
- 0.38 to 0.48
- 0.48 to 0.52
- 0.52 to 0.62
- 0.61 to 0.80
- 0.80 to 1

Comment: use `if .. else if` .. `if(x < 0.10) ... else if (x < 0.20) ... else if (x < 0.30)` etc

Comment: *Which* specific intervals? It's important for the solution. Please post your whole and real code.

Comment: Looking at your current code... What do you think happens when `incomingValue` is something like `0.095`?

Comment: Added all the used intervals in the code.

Comment: @Bergi: Please do not encourage people to "post [their] whole and real code". We have a hard enough time trying to remind people to post a [MCVE] as it is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, "complete" not "whole", but especially for "*How to dry this up*" questions it's necessary to post the entire thing with all the repetitions and the actual values, not some `"something.png"` pseudo examples

Comment: @Bergi: A well-formed [MCVE] that reproduces the problem and clearly explains the requirements is what we need. Abstracting away real-world detail and replacing with `"something.png"` pseudo-examples is just fine. It makes the questions re-usable, which is a requirement for every question on this site!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Without the details, it's not easily recognisable which generalisations can be made and which not. I've had this happen several times that after drying up code the OP commented something along the lines "*but I can't use `setValueIcon = setValueName+".png"` because my actual values are x, y and z*"

Comment: @Bergi: That means it was an incomplete MCVE. A post with a MCVE doesn't suffer from that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember the single responsibility principle. Take that code out to a separate function like so:

```
function determineNameAndIcon(incomingValue) {
  if (incomingValue < 0.10) { 
    return { 
      name: "something",
      icon: "something.png"
    };
  }
  if (incomingValue < 0.20) { 
    return {
      name: "somethingElse",
      icon: "somethingElse.png"
    };
  }
  // etc
  return {
    name: "somethingDefault",
    icon: "somethingDefault.png"
  };
}

// ...

var incomingValue; // Set by an API
const {
  name: setValueName,
  icon: setValueIcon
} = determineNameAndIcon(incomingValue);
```

Notice that `determineNameAndIcon` is still a very long function with repeating parts. This can be further refactored to a data-driven version:

```
const nameAndIconList = [
  {
    maxValue: 0.10,
    name: "something",
    icon: "something.png"
  },
  {
    maxValue: 0.20,
    name: "somethingElse",
    icon: "somethingElse.png"
  },
  // ...
];

const nameAndIconDefault = {
  name: "somethingDefault",
  icon: "somethingDefault.png"
};

function determineNameAndIcon(incomingValue) {
  for (let item of nameAndIconList) {
    if (incomingValue < item.maxValue) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return nameAndIconDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function findValue(incomingValue){

    var itemValues = [
      [.06, "valueName", "valueIcon"],  
      [.08, "valueName", "valueIcon"],
      [.09, "valueName", "valueIcon"],
      [.1, "valueName", "valueIcon"],

    ]


  var foundValues = itemValues.
        filter(v=>v[0] >= incomingValue)
        .sort();

  if(foundValues.length == 0){
     throw "incoming value not found."
  } 
  return foundValues[0];
}

let value = findValue(.079);

console.log( value );
```

This is assuming that you want the lowest portion of the range to be the one selected (just reverse the sort if you want it to be the highest).

Answer (score 1):

A solution using an array where you set the ranges for your results:

```js
var categories = [{something: [0, 0.1]}, 
                  {somethingElse: [0.1, 0.2]}, 
                  {somethingElse2: [0.2, 0.3]}, 
                  {anotherSomething: [0.3, 1]}];

function res(number){ return Object.keys(categories.filter(function(elem) {
  var key = elem[Object.keys(elem)];
  return number >= key[0] && number < key[1]
})[0])[0]};

var incomingValue = 0.12;

var setValueName = res(incomingValue);
var setValueIcon = res(incomingValue) + ".png";
console.log(setValueName, setValueIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb I will refactor this code like this but it's not really standard patter :

```
var incomingValue=0.08; // Set by an API
var setValueName;
var setValueIcon;

switch(true) {
    case incomingValue < 0.10 :
        setValueName = "something"; 
        setValueIcon ="something.png";
        alert("Hello World !");
        break;
    case incomingValue > 0.09 && incomingValue < 0.20 :
        setValueName = "somethingElse"; 
        setValueIcon ="somethingElse.png";
        alert("Hello !");
        break;
    default :
        alert("Adele !");
        break;
}
```

The mortal will use the if...else if... condition like this :

```
var incomingValue; // Set by an API
var setValueName;
var setValueIcon;
if (incomingValue < 0.10 ) { 
    setValueName = "something"; 
    setValueIcon ="something.png" 
} **else** if (incomingValue > 0.09 && incomingValue < 0.20 ) { 
    setValueName = "somethingElse"; 
    setValueIcon ="somethingElse.png" 
}
```

But I dont like this way...My opinion :)

Comment: I have never thought of using a switch-case this way :D adding it to my list of "What does this code do"s.

Comment: @Xatenev It's actually completely valid and a very useful aspect of JS switch statements. Advising people not to do something that works by design and is neater than the alternative seems rather daft.